# Cambiar la disposición de "yyyy/mm/dd" a "dd/mm/yyyy" en Mysql

Tags: java, mysql

Hola tengo hecha una tabla **mysql**, donde una de las columnas es de fecha, la tengo declarada como 'date' y acepta el igreso de un string con estas características **"yyyy-mm-dd"**.

Sin embargo el input html mas parecido que encontré es el **type="date"**, su estructura es **"dd-mm-yyyy"**.

Hay alguna forma de cambiar la disposición de los dias, meses y años de las columnas mysql ???.

Vi que hay una función en mysql que dice FORMAT y que usa `%Y %d %m`, pero realmente no lo entiendo.

```
package org.comunidadIT.proyecto.controladores;

import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.PreparedStatement;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

import javax.ws.rs.Consumes;
import javax.ws.rs.FormParam;
import javax.ws.rs.POST;
import javax.ws.rs.Path;
import javax.ws.rs.Produces;
import javax.ws.rs.core.MediaType;

import org.comunidadIT.proyecto.accesoDatos.AutenticarUsuario;
import org.comunidadIT.proyecto.accesoDatos.ConexionAeropuerto;
import org.comunidadIT.proyecto.entidades.Vuelo;

import com.google.gson.Gson;



@Path("/adminVuelos")
public class AdminVuelos {

@POST
@Path("/agregarVuelo")
@Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
@Consumes(MediaType.APPLICATION_FORM_URLENCODED)
public String agregarVuelo(@FormParam("usuario") String usuario, @FormParam("pass") String pass, @FormParam("empresa") String empresa, @FormParam("destino") String destino, @FormParam("escalas") int escalas, @FormParam("salida") String salida, @FormParam("pago") String pago, @FormParam("precio") float precio){

    Gson gson= new Gson();
    List<Vuelo> listado= new ArrayList<>();

    try{
        ConexionAeropuerto c= new ConexionAeropuerto();
        Connection con= c.connectarAhora();

        if(con !=null){
            PreparedStatement ps;
            String sql="INSERT INTO vuelos(empresa, destino, escalas, salida, pago, precio) values(?,?,?,?,?,?)";
            ps= con.prepareStatement(sql);

            ps.setString(1, empresa);
            ps.setString(2, destino);
            ps.setInt(3, escalas);
            ps.setDate(4, java.sql.Date.valueOf("03-03-2017"));
            ps.setString(5, pago);
            ps.setFloat(6, precio);

            ps.executeUpdate();
            ps.close();

            listado.add(new Vuelo(1,"asd","asd", 2,"asd","asd",2));

            String str_toJson= gson.toJson(listado);
            return "EL vuelo fue agregado con exito:  "+ str_toJson ;
        }

    }
    catch(Exception e)
    {
        return "Los datos no han sido ingresados o no se pudo conectar a la BD.";
    }


    return "EL vuelo fue agregado a la base de datos";
  }


}
```

Comment: hola amigo, podrias agregar a la pregunta el `Query` que estas usando.

Comment: En unos minutos actualizo la pregunta con la query

Comment: tu problema es la cadena de entrada???

Comment: donde esta el query de la fecha?, osea donde encontraste el FORMAT

Comment: Perdón si no me expresé bien, el format lo vi googleando en w3cschools.com pero no no entendí en qué parte de my tabla mysql tenia que colocar el format.

Comment: Es mejor guardar la fecha en la tabla de este modo: YYYYMMDD sin más. Y luego al presentar los datos le das el formato que quieras. Al guardar tus datos de forma plana, sin guiones u otros símbolos será más fácil operar con ellos, por ejemplo hacer cálculos entre dos fechas, etc.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Se puede desde java y desde la base de datos:

Primero que todo, busca donde tengas el formato de la fecha que debe llamarse

> format

Cuando lo encuentres, cámbialo por esto:

> Antes:

```
SELECT DATE_FORMAT( NOW( ) ,  '%Y %d %m' )
```

> Despues:

```
 SELECT DATE_FORMAT( NOW( ) ,  '%d %m %Y' )
```

De esta manera podras tener el formato de fecha normal.

Este otro metodo tambien puede servirte si no encuentras en la base de datos el

> format

este método se hace con java:

La manera de hacer que salga el formato de la fecha normalmente, lo único que tienes que hacer es agregarle el `tostring()`

> Antes:

`java.sql.Date.valueOf("03-03-2017");`

> Despues:

`java.sql.Date.valueOf("03-03-2017").tostring();`

De estas 2 maneras podras tener el formato de la fecha normal.

Comment: Hola, mi problema es que no sé donde colocar el format, es dentro de la base de datos mysql ?

Comment: a ok amigo ahora si te explicaste

Comment: si, tiene que especificar la consulta de esa manera

Comment: me tira error si le quiero poner el toString()

Comment: @berlot83 Favor de pasar al chat: http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/30872/stack-overflow-en-espanol

Answer (score 6):

Usa la función [`DATE_FORMAT(columnafecha, formato)`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_date-format), la cual sirve para dar formato a la fecha y mostrarla como se le indique. Ejemplo:

```sql
SELECT DATE_FORMAT( NOW( ) ,  '%d-%m-%Y' )
```

Resultado:

```
30-03-2017
```

Answer (score 0):

En MySQL se pueden cambiar o predeterminar los formatos de tipo de dato de algunas columnas de tablas en la base de datos pero es recommendable que los tipos de datos date y datetime no sean cambiados. El problema de la culturización, internacionalización y estandarización es un fenómeno que causa bastante problemas a nivel global e igualmente en términos de tecnología. Solamente unos pocos paises en el mundo utilizan el formato mm-dd-yyyy, de hecho la mayoría usan el dd-mm-yyyy y personalmente veo muy pocos motivos por los cuales no se pueda usar un solo formato de fecha estándar pero ya esto abre puertas a otros debates que no conciernen acá.

Acá puedes chequear el hilo de debate de este tema en el sitio official:
[cambiar formato de fecha en MySQL](https://forums.mysql.com/read.php?35,131559,213552#msg-213552)
, ahí igualmente puedes chequear que la mejor técnica es usar las funciones DATE_FORMAT y DATETIME_FORMAT para cada caso.
Iguamente puedes manejar la conversión en el java framework e incluso hasta puedes manipular el output en el lado del cliente(navegador) para mostrar el formato deseado porque el resultado final siempre es una cadena de caracteres.